# Java string matching with enum

Tags: java, string-matching

I am having an odd issue where an if statement is not evaluating to true when two strings which are seemingly the same are checked. I have the following method :

```
public void render(Cell.Context context, TaskSchedule object, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
    String taskName = getValue(object);
    System.out.println(taskName);
    if (String.valueOf(ServerTask.RUN_CYME_EXPORT).equals(taskName)) {
                taskName = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + taskName;
            }
}
```

taskName will print out "Run CYME Export" and the enum ServerTask looks as follows:

```
public enum ServerTask {
    .....
    RUN_CYME_EXPORT("Run CYME Export"),
    .....
}
```

The printed string and the string in the enum are exactly the same spellings. I have also tried this to no avail:

```
if(String.valueOf(ServerTask.RUN_CYME_EXPORT).equals(taskName)){
    .....
}
```

Comment: What does `String.valueOf(ServerTask.RUN_CYME_EXPORT)` return?

Comment: Does your enum implement `toString()`? If so, show it. And show your enum constructor.

Comment: Check if taskName has spaces. You can compare with case insensitive and make a trim before.

Comment: String.valueOf(ServerTask.RUN_CYME_EXPORT) returns "RUN_CYME_EXPORT" and no the enum does not implement toString()

Comment: @jeremy And what does taskName contain?

Comment: taskName is a string which prints is "Run CYME Export"

Comment: @jeremy So they obviously don't equal each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The enum should be something like:

```
public enum ServerTask {
    RUN_CYME_EXPORT("Run CYME Export");
    private final String value;
    private ServerTask(String aValue) {this.value = aValue;}
    public String value() {return value;}
}
```

So from the outside:

```
if (ServerTask.RUN_CYME_EXPORT.value().equals(taskName)) {
   // whatever
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should compare the string containing in enum, not by value of.

Comment: That depends on the implementation, if any, of toString() in the enum. If toString() returns the internal string, OP's code should work.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the constructor for ServerTask it will be assigning the parameter value to some field.

If you want to compare with the value of that variable you need to call the corresponding getter.

String.valueOf(ServerTask.RUN_CYME_EXPORT) probably returns the string "RUN_CYME_EXPORT"